# Is there any URL structure for google voice to have number input ready?

Tags: text, sms, voice

So like gmail has something like that :

https://mail.google.com/mail/?to=inbox@example.com&bcc=admin@example.com&subject=Hey#compose

Does Voice has anything closer so i can have a link ready to click in and it takes user to page they will click send and the text goes ?

Even just transferring number is ok for me. It will save time.

or any free web service lets me do that ?

Huge thanks !

p.s: I'll create a user script for a website so, i'm not webmaster of that website to use it's api